# WYSIWYG HTML or XML editor?

Tags: html, text-editor, xml, html-editor, table

Do you know what-you-see-is-what-you-get editor with following features:

1. Designed for editing HTML or XML (or other **open** markup formatted) files.
2. Open-source
3. Capable of operating:

   - text
   - images
   - tables
4. Available on Windows
5. Offline

I've lots of miscellaneous data in form of text notes, pictures and tables. Now I have an idea to organize all this stuff and make some sort of diary. I am intended to bind it in one file with text & links. But I need an open-source solution and have to use open human-readable format. Because I've already had some headache after partial data corruption of .xlsx and .docx documents. Need something more simple and reliable.

Comment: Can you explain what you plan to do with such an editor?

Comment: You want to write in html? Or just have the results saved in html?

Comment: I want save and load results in HTML or XML or other open markup format. Just like you do it with Word and .doc files. You can edit it having no idea about .doc format structure.

Comment: "or other open markup formatted": Would Markdown be acceptable to you then? Because in that case, I could check what I've set up on my Windows machine at work (at home, I prefer Linux, which is the only OS used here apart from Android ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [Red Notebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/):

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform including Windows
- Diary like Journal layout
- Searchable
- Text, Images, Links & tags can be inserted
- Simple set of formatting commands that are very similar to here.
- File storage is a directory structure of *JournalName*/*yyyy-mm.txt* where the file contents are YAML structured text.
- Backup format is .zip
- Export the journal to plain text, HTML, Latex or PDF

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Summernote](http://summernote.org/).

I have used this in my project. It is a good one.

- You can download the plugin and use it as offline.
- It is open source.
- It have feature that code view. You edit the content as html codes.
- Capable of adding LINK, IMAGE and TABLE

Comment: Can you add something explaining *why* this program meets (all) the requirements? Your answer is now [in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you. what you mean by "why this program meets (all) the requirements?"

Comment: Can it do everything the OP asks? E.g. (s)he asks for **offline** software for Windows, and if I follow the link it seems to be **online**. Is it for websites only and requires Bootstrap? That would make it completely *unfit* for the OP! Additionally: Why do you say it is a good one? Facts? Good answers here need some context, not just a link and an opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app BlueGriffon that is a WYSIWYG website builder. It's free and I think it meets your requirements. There is an excellent tutorial on how to use this. Just Google 'BlueGriffon tutorial'. I'm using this to build my web page. It's an excellent app with many nice features.

The tutorial has a chapter on posting your website to a service for others to see. You can just skip that part. rest of tutorial is about building a web page.